# Drupal-8 Commerce - Adding multiple add to cart buttons to multiple product variations

Tags: drupal-8, commerce, product-variations

I want to display multiple variations for a product as follows:

each variation has different colors which can be purchased in different sizes.

I want all the color variations to be displayed on the product display but have a separate add to cart for each different size for the ordering.

Something like how the product variations and prices are displayed according to color here:
https://www.dhgshop.it/art-fibre-tops-lana-merino-extra-fine_0_0_1_1_1.php

I am using the Commerce Variation Cart Form and it displays all my color options nicely but I need to add in different prices (for the different quantities) for each color variation.

The pricing table will not work here since I need different add to cart buttons per variation.